# Object reference not set to an instance of an object when calling asynchronous method

Tags: c#, async-await

I have an interface for all social network services. Most of them are async task methods.

For Twitter implementation, since Twitter does not provide user birthdays through its REST API, wanted to return null.

The interface method GetUserBirthDayAsync is implemented as follows for the Twitter service:

```
public Task<DateTime?> GetUserBirthDayAsync(){
    return null; // because twitter does not provide user birthday
}
```

and this is how I used the method:

```
DateTime? birthDate = await socialNetworkService.GetUserBirthDayAsync();
```

But I can't get to pass this error: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` even though I'm not using the object.
The error occurred in setting the value for the birthdate variable.

What is happening? What is causing the exception?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
public Task<DateTime?> GetUserBirthDayAsync()
{
    return Task.Run(() => (DateTime?)null);
}
```

Or, better way to do the same:

```
public Task<DateTime?> GetUserBirthDayAsync()
{
    return Task.FromResult<DateTime?>(null);
}
```

When you just return `null` that means, your Task is `null`, not result of async method.

Comment: `Task.FromResult(<DateTime?>null)` would be a much better way to state the same thing.

Comment: @spender added your example. Feel free to edit answers, if you think, it can be improved!

Answer (score 5):

An alternative could be to just use the `Task.FromResult<DateTime?>(null)`

as.

```
public Task<DateTime?> GetUserBirthDayAsync()
{
    return Task.FromResult<DateTime?>(null);
}
```

[MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194922(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Creates a Task that's completed successfully with the
>   specified result.

Pretty much the same as the other options but IMHO it looks much cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

> even though am not using the object

Yes, you **are** using the object. The object that is `null` is the `Task<DateTime?>` you return from `GetUserBirthDayAsync()`. And you use it when you try to `await` this task.

So the `NullReferenceException` is raised by the `await` (or the code the compiler creates for it).

So what you probably want to do is to return a `Task<DateTime?>` that returns a `null` as result type:

```
public Task<DateTime?> GetUserBirthDayAsync(){
    return Task.Run(() => (DateTime?)null);
}
```

Comment: Vogt you are right that was what I thought. Thanks it works now

Answer (score 1):

You call await on null. I think you had something like this in mind:

```
public Task<DateTime?> GetUserBirthDayAsync(){
    return Task.Run(() => (DateTime?)null); // because twitter does not provide user birthday like faceBK
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also make the method async

```
public async Task<DateTime?> GetUserBirthDayAsync(){
    return null; // because twitter does not provide user birthday
}
```